# Can't figure out how to use synchronize.js in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, synchronize

I'm trying to use the module [synchronize.js](http://alexeypetrushin.github.io/synchronize/docs/index.html) in my node.js app, but I am failing.  Functions are still running out of order, and I'm not getting my data.
Here is a general snippet of my code.

```
// an object with devices to migrate
var devices2Migrate =
{
device_array: [],

init: function ( done )
{
    sync.fiber(function()
    {
      //do init stuff
      console.log( 'yay we have a DB connector' );
      DB1.connect(function(err)
      {
          console.log( 'Database 1 is connected ...' );
      }
      DB2.connect(function(err)
      {
          console.log( 'Database 2 is connected ...' );
      }

    }, done);
 },

 loadDevices2Migrate: function ( done )
 {
    var self = this;
    sync.fiber(function()
    {
       //get stuff from DB using query()
    }, done);
 }
}; //end of object

// load up all the data for the devices using the old style tables
    sync.fiber(function(){
        sync.await( devices2Migrate.init( sync.defer() ));
        sync.await( devices2Migrate.loadDevices2Migrate( sync.defer() ) );

        console.log(  devices2Migrate.device_array );
        console.log(  "size: " + devices2Migrate.device_array.length );
    });
```

But what happens is that the console.log shows that the functions are not waiting:

```
yay we have a DB connector
[]
size: 0
Database 1 is connected ...
Database 2 is connected ...
```

Can anyone point me to what I'm doing wrong?  I can fill in the method bodies more if needed, I was just trying to keep it simple at first. 
I know my methods( functions ) are correct, because if I wrap the bottom console.log calls (the ones in the fiber) in a setTimeout callback, then I do get my data.

Comment: @Oliver Can you provide a link or something.  There is nothing in the synchronize.js module that talks about needing such things.  [This page](https://mixmax.com/blog/node-fibers-using-synchronize-js) indicates that promises are not used/needed with the synchronize module.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use the sync module?

Comment: Promises are easier and more of the "industry standard" if you will

Comment: Care to help out with an example of how I might do this with promises?  Thanks!

Comment: I will provide you with a promise module and an example

Comment: you forgot to "synchronize" the connect methods. `sync(DB1, 'connect')` (repeat for DB2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) package.  It was more "user friendly" in that it worked!

**EDIT:**
in async, I did this:

```
// load up all the data for the devices using the old style tables
async.series(
    devices2Migrate.init( callback ),
    devices2Migrate.loadDevices2Migrate( callback )
){
    // land here when done
    console.log(  devices2Migrate.device_array );
    console.log(  "size: " + devices2Migrate.device_array.length );
});
```

Comment: i mean... sync woulda worked if you used it properly, just sayin.

Comment: Thanks for the down vote!  @Kevin: Maybe some better help would have gotten me over the hump.  But as you can see there were zero answers for syncronize.js.  I wasn't able to solve my problem using synchronize so I tried async.js and following the documentation, it just worked!  So that's my answer and I'm sticking to it.  Thanks for YOUR help though!

Comment: The downvote was because you didn't provide a solution. I'm sure async.js helped you (and i think it's a better alternative to synchronize.js,) but make the answer useful!

Comment: Point taken (no pun intended).  I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When working with Node, [this is my favourite package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/when) for promises:

Simple promise:

```
return when.promise(function(resolveCallback, rejectCallback) {
        //do something here
    var blah = foo("bar");

    //return callback like this
    resolveCallback();
});
```

Chained promise:

return when.promise(function(resolveCallback, rejectCallback) {
        //do something here
    var blah = foo("bar");

```
//return callback like this
resolveCallback();
```

}).then(x);

```
var x = function(){
     return when.promise(function(resolveCallback, rejectCallback) {
      //do something here
      var blah = foo("bar");

      //return callback like this
      resolveCallback();
        });
};
```